# TEXTJOIN no duplicates no blanks, table references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, textjoin, excel-tables

I have this table:
[image]

on Cell A4 i want the value "Orange,Banana,Peach,Mango,Melon,Watermelon,Apple".

this is the requirements i have:

- table format (so instead of cells like B2,C2,etc - I need [@Fruit 1], [@Fruit 2], [@Fruit 3], [@Fruit 4], [@Fruit 5], [@Fruit 6], [@Fruit 7], [@Fruit 8])
- I have more than 8 Fruits normally, i have like 40, for the sake of the example i showed only 8.
- no duplicates - if a fruit returns twice show it only once.
- no blanks

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would get the list of fruits then use unique() to get a unique list, after that you could sort alphabetically and the ampersand (&) will join cell contents.

Comment: Hi Mike, what if it's more difficult to get the list of fruit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(Table1[@[Fruit 1]:[Fruit 8]],1))
```

This will autofill the rest of 'Fruits' down to `A4`.

Comment: it did the job, well done JvdV